# Submission is successful text not going even after reloading

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, backend

I'm currently working on a small PHP project, which includes a simple form using xampp server. The form is working but the issue that I'm facing is that I want a text "form submission successful" to appear when a user submits the form. 
**Now the problem is that once someone visits my page for the first time it is not visible but once he submits it then even after reloading the page for several times, it is not disappearing.**

[image: The marked text is not disappearing]

Below is my PHP code:

I have declared a variable 'insert', I've first declared it to be false, then I'm changing its value to be true when data is inserted successfully. I'm saying in my HTML file that if the 'insert' value is true then print this.

```
            <?php
        $insert= false;
        if (isset($_POST['name'])){

            //Connection Variables
            $server= "localhost";
            $username="root";
            $password="";

            //Create a database connection
            $con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password);

            //Check for Connection success
            if(!$con){
                die("Connection to this database failed due to".mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            //Collect Post var
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $age = $_POST['age'];
            $gender = $_POST['gender'];
            $phone = $_POST['phone'];
            $desc = $_POST['desc'];

            $sql= " INSERT INTO `trip`.`trip` (`name`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `phone`, `desc`, `date`) 
            VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$gender', '$email', '$phone', '$desc', current_timestamp()); ";


            //Execute query

            if($con->query($sql)==true){
                // echo "Successfully inserted";
                $insert= true;

            }
            else{
                echo "Error: $sql <br> $con->error";
            }


            //Close connection
            $con-> close();

        }
        ?>


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Sriracha&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Trip Form</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <img class="bg" src="bg.jpg" alt="Travel">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Welcome to Book Karo Apni Trip</h1>
                <p>Enter your Details to confirm your participation.</p>
                <?php
                if($insert==true){
                echo "<p class='submitMsg'>Thanks for submitting your form. We are happy to see you joining us for the trip</p> ";
                }
                ?>
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter your age">
                    <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="Enter your gender">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your mobile number">
                    <textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10"placeholder="Enter any other information here"></textarea>
                    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
                    <!-- <button class="btn">Reset</button> -->
                    </form> 


            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            document.cookie = 'cookiename=; expires=' + d.toGMTString() + ';';
        };
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Below is my CSS file:

```
        *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .container{
        max-width: 80%;
        /* background-color: rgb(229, 145, 229); */
        padding:34px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .container h1,p{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Sriracha', 'cursive';
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    p{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Sriracha', 'cursive';
    }
    .submitMsg{
        font-size: 18px;
        color: green;
        background-color:#ccc;
        
    }
    input,textarea{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 11px auto;
        padding:7px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 6px;
        outline: none;

    }
    form{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .btn{
        color: white;background: purple;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-radius: 14px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .bg{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

Comment: Are you _reloading_ the page? Maybe with `F5` or `ctrl+F5` or by clicking on the refresh button in the browser?

Comment: @endeavour Yes I have tried reloading it using normal reload(Ctrl+R), and I even tried the hard reload, and 'empty cache and hard reload' in the developer tools. But it is always visible, once someone submits the form.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

When reloading a page the `post` data is resent. You may have noticed many bank or e-commerce sites displaying a notice to not reload the page. That is because the action associated with the form is re-processed (they have protection against it though).

So what is happening is everytime you reload your webpage the form is resubmitted. If you have provided the full codes, then each reload will result in a new row being inserted.

There are many ways to allow a reload without re-submission of the data. Some examples are

1. Redirect user to a different page.
2. Use ajax to process the submission
3. Before inserting data to mysql check for duplicate values.

These could be the basic approach. Each of these are very well documents on SO as well as outside.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use an alert() instead. Or you could navigate that page to some other page like LOGIN PAGE.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alert or a toast to indicate a success/error message